# Not able to extend ObjC class using Protocol in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, protocols

I am trying to extend an ObjC class for dependency injection using a protocol in swift , this class isn't owned by me so I cant make changes. For one of the method its working but for other Xcode always says that the class isn't confirming to the protocol and suggests me to add the method to the extension

Below is the declaration in ObjC header

```
- (BOOL) subscribeToTopic:(NSString *)topic
                      QoS:(AWSIoTMQTTQoS)qos
          extendedCallback:(AWSIoTMQTTExtendedNewMessageBlock)callback;
```

Here is the protocol and its extension

```
protocol PopAWSIoTDataManagerProtocol {

    func publishString(_ data:String, onTopic:String, QoS:AWSIoTMQTTQoS) -> Bool
    func subscribeToTopic(_ topic: String, qoS: AWSIoTMQTTQoS, extendedCallback: (NSObject, String, Data) -> Void) -> Bool

}

extension AWSIoTDataManager : PopAWSIoTDataManagerProtocol {

}
```

Notice the error below it suggests me exactly same func to be added to extension which I already have added to main protocol

[image]

Not sure whats wrong , as I was able to add another method just fine.

Article used as a reference is this https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/the-complete-guide-to-network-unit-testing-in-swift-db8b3ee2c327

Comment: If I just keep the publishString method all runs fine

Answer (score 0):

You must confirm protocol `PopAWSIoTDataManagerProtocol`, cuz it `extension` of class `AWSIoTDataManager`

Or you can try this

```
extension PopAWSIoTDataManagerProtocol where Self: AWSIoTDataManager {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The protocol that you have defined has all function's to implemented as mandatory.

You need to define them as optional. Either you define them as optional or implement all of them which was the error image that you have attached is asking for.

```
@objc protocol PopAWSIoTDataManagerProtocol {

    @objc optional func publishString(_ data:String, onTopic:String, QoS:AWSIoTMQTTQoS) -> Bool
    @objc optional func subscribeToTopic(_ topic: String, qoS: AWSIoTMQTTQoS, extendedCallback: (NSObject, String, Data) -> Void) -> Bool

}
```

Default behavior of Protocol, when implemented is that you have to override all the methods. These are categorized as Protocol Requirements.

There are Optional Protocol Requirements , which do not have to be implemented by types that conform to the protocol.

To achieve Optional Protcol Requirements, the **protocol** and the **requirement i.e the optional function**  must be marked as @objc.

Comment: Can you elaborate this a bit more ? Why they need to be optional ? When the original class already has those functions ?

Comment: A clarification when I had just the publishString function it had no issues al run fine

Comment: It will still throw the same error, as for the object to conform PopAWSIoTDataManagerProtocol protocol, you need all methods to implement. that's the default behavior. I received the error even if had just publish String.

Comment: Did you read please ? I said it worked fine with a single method error started getting in after adding second method